# How to synchronize branching between independent git repositories?

Tags: git

I have two independent git repositories; one to hold the code for my data analysis project, and one to hold the output of running the code. So, it looks like this:

```
.
|-- project_output
|   |-- .git
|   |-- output_sample1
|   |-- output_sample2
|   `-- output_sample3
`-- project_code
    |-- .git
    |-- code
    |   `-- all_my_scripts.sh
    `-- output -> ../project_output
```

The output data consists of very large text-based files, and I keep it in `project_output`. The project itself is open source on GitHub, and is tracked on `project_code`. I use `git` to track changes in both.

When I want to add a new feature to the `project_code`, or debug or alter an old feature, I make a branch:

```
project_code$ git checkout -b fix-some-bug
project_code$ # make some changes, run the new code
project_code$ # save output in output -> ../project_output
```

Now, I can review changes to the output in `project_output`:

```
project_output$ git status
project_output$ git diff
```

If I want to keep the new output, I would make a commit:

```
project_output$ git add -u; git add .
project_output$ git commit -m "Update results from project_code/fix-some-bug branch"
```

However, it gets tedious and difficult to track the output from different branches of `project_code` in `project_output` like this. I think it would be much easier if there was a system where creating & changing branches in `project_code` would be mirrored in `project_output`. For example:

```
project_code$ git checkout -b fix-some-bug # project_output/fix-some-bug is created
project_code$ git checkout master # project_output switches to master branch as well
project_code$ git merge fix-some-bug # project_output merges fix-some-bug to master as well
```

I guess it sounds a lot like I want the benefits of having a single repository, while maintain the security of keeping sensitive data from ever touching my public repo.

Answer (score 1):

To summarize, you'd kind of like to have one *public* repository that has code-only, and a second *private* repository that gets its code from the public repository, but then *adds on* data.  It turns out that this is *really easy to do* (although it's *also* easy to accidentally publish your private data, if you are not careful).

Git is very much like the Star Trek [Borg collective](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borg_(Star_Trek)): it likes to take another repository's technological distinctiveness—i.e., new commits—and add it to its own.  In fact, this is exactly what `git fetch` does.

To use `git fetch`, you tell your Git to call up some other Git, usually via Internet-phone at some URL.  Your Git then gets a list of all their *references*—branch and tag names mainly, but also other things.  (More precisely, your Git gets whatever their Git is willing to *show* you, but by default, they show you *everything*.)  These reference names point to specific commits.<sup>1</sup>  Your Git then asks for any commits you don't already have, and any other objects needed as well to complete them.

Since the direction of `git fetch` is "from them, to us", all the transfers work that way.  (The nearest thing to an opposite of `git fetch` is `git push`, where we instruct our Git to call up another Git and send, to *them*, *our* technological distinctiveness.  Obviously you won't want to do that from your private repository.)  Once our Git has all the objects, it can either stop there, or set up names to *remember* the objects.

The names we get, if we tell our Git to save names, are *our* names, not theirs.  When we copy commits using their *branch* names as starting-points to find the commits, though, we normally have our Git save these via *remote-tracking branch names* in our own repository.  For instance, if their `master` had commit `deadbee` that we did not have, we copy their `deadbee` into our repository, and then make our `origin/master` remember this hash ID `deadbee`.<sup>2</sup>  (If the parent commit of `deadbee` is `ac0ffee`, we have our Git take their `ac0ffee` too, unless we already have it, and so on.)

If we have our Git pick up *tag*-named commits (and/or tag objects as in footnote 1), we have our Git store these tag names in *our* tag names, not in "remote tags", so if they added a tag named `v2.3`, we set a new tag for ourselves also named `v2.3`.  The fancy renaming is only for branches, by default.  But this is under your own control: it's *your* repository, so you control everything.

In any case, you can instruct your Git not to set up your own names at all.  If you do that, you rely on something `git fetch` has done from the Dim Time, which is that it saves *every* name it got in `.git/FETCH_HEAD`, always.  A normal `git fetch` *overwrites* the previous `FETCH_HEAD`, so you must extract the commit IDs from that file, and do something to remember them, before you run `git fetch` again.

Meanwhile, though, whether or not you have set your own names for their commits, *you have all their commits* (well, all the ones you instructed your `git fetch` to copy).  Your Git has, Borg-like, added *their* technological distinctiveness to your own.

Hence, all you have to do is set up your *public* repository as a named remote in your *private* repository, and run `git fetch`:

```
~/repos/private$ git remote add public https://github.com/...
```

or:

```
~/repos/private$ git remote add public file://~me/repos/public
```

or whatever URL you like.  After that, running:

```
~/repos/private$ git fetch public
```

will have your Git call up another Git (perhaps on your own machine!<sup>3</sup>) using the saved URL, and download into your private repository, any new unique commits found in "their" (your other) repository.  It will name "their" branches `public/master` and so on, i.e., rename their branch from *X* to `public/X`, because the name we used with `git add`, to create this "remote", was `public`.

Just be careful not to push your private commits up to your public repository.  Git, like the Borg, is really happy to add *new* things, but will fight you to the death about *removing* things.  Well, perhaps not *death*, exactly. :-) But once data have escaped like this, anyone could clone it, and even if you manage to scrub it away from the public repository quickly, it *might* have been copied and widely distributed.

---

<sup>1</sup>Tag names can point to any of the four object types.  Often they will point to an *annotated tag* object, and the tag object then points to a commit, but sometimes tag names just point directly to commits anyway.  Branch names may only point to commits.

<sup>2</sup>This is where `fetch` and `push` are different: when we send then a commit from our `master`, we usually ask them to set *their* `master`.  They don't have a "push-tracking branch" for us.  However, if we are using pull requests, we do this "please set your master" in an even more roundabout way, by sending our master to a name they can recognize as "please *look at* this, then decide whether you like it" rather than the more automatic "please automatically take this as long as it fits easily".

In other words, pull requests are the push equivalent of remote-tracking branches: a "safe place" to store things that you don't entirely *trust* yet, so that you can look at, and decide about, these new objects before incorporating them.  Because their names tend to be terrible—pull requests are usually numbered, and there's no obvious connection between "PR#1234" and, e.g., "I'd like you to incorporate this into feature/california-bear", some people do this differently.  They push to a public repository of their own, then announce, e.g., by email: "I have new stuff for you in *my* feature/beetle, why don't you go `git fetch` from my public repository."  This serves exactly the same purpose: you make your commit `cafedad` available by some name, at some URL.  It's then up to the other person, using either the same URL or a different one, to retrieve your commits, either because they are already at that URL under some weird name like `pull/1234/head`, or at your URL under the name `feature/beetle`.

<sup>3</sup>When copying files from one repository on your own machine to another repository on your own machine—i.e., using path URLs or `file://` URLs—your Git may wind up playing both the role of "your Git" and "their Git" in fetch and push conversations.  From a high level view, however, the *effect* is the same as if there were two separate Gits, working in two separate repositories, exchanging data through a relatively narrow channel, as if over an Internet connection.